# laravel livewire data not show in modal

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I can pass the data to component but in modal by Alpine js the data is null.

this is class:

```
public $code, $products;

    public function getData($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $this->code = $product->code;
    }

  public function render()
    {

        $this->products = Product::latest()->get();

        return view('livewire.cabin');
    }
```

and this is the component:

```
<div x-data="{open: false}">
    <section>
if I use $code here the code value is shown !!!
<div>{{ $code }}</div>
        <div class="slideCabin">
            @foreach($products as $product)
                <div>
<img
@click="open = true"
wire:click="getData({{ $product->id }})"
src="/images/allproducts/{{ $product->cover }}"
>
                </div>
            @endforeach

        </div>


    </section>
```

this is modal which is open by Alpine js by click on  tag:

```
    <div id="backmodal" x-show="open">
but, the code value is null:
 <p>{{ $code }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please show your full components and the blade. its not clear enough to me. I'm working with livewire for a while now. Hope I can help you

Comment: I will post another subject which covers my problem. please consider it.

Comment: sure brother....

Comment: tkx brother

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650712/laravel-livewire-how-to-pass-the-id-or-data-to-another-component-by-click

Comment: checkout my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666517/10804409

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel livewire, how to pass the id or data to another component by click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650712/laravel-livewire-how-to-pass-the-id-or-data-to-another-component-by-click)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to check if the code value has changed before calling it in the modal.
you got null value because it's been called before assigning it any value.

```
@if($code)
<p> {{ $code }} </p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.x style:

```
<p> {{ $code ?? "" }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you have to add some validation rules.
use the "public function rules()" option