# laravel livewire, how to pass the id or data to another component by click

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two components Posts and Post, Posts show the posts and by clicking the image I want to show the data of clicked post in another component.

**Posts class and component down below:**

Component View:

```
<div class="post" x-data="{open:false}">
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div>
      <h1>{{ $post->name }}</h1>
      <h3>{{ $post->body }}</h3>
      <img @click="open = !open" wire:click="showPost({{ $post->id }})" src="{{ $post->image }}" alt="">
    </div>
  @endforeach


<livewireL:post>

    </div>
```

Component Class:

```
class Posts extends Component
{


  public $posts, $post;

  public function mount(){
    $this->posts = Post::all();

  }


  public function showPost($id){
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->post = $post;
  }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.posts');
    }
}
```

and this is the **Post component and class** that I want to show the clicked data in this component, I have tried $emit and many as documentation but no result.

Component view which I want to render that data:

```
<div x-show="open">
  <h1>{{ $post->name }}</h1>
  <h3>{{ $post->body }}</h3>
  <img src="{{ $post->image }}">
</div>
```

Class which I want to pass data:

```
class Post extends Component
{

  public $post;



  public function mount($id)
  {
    $this->post = \App\Post::find($id);
  }



    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.post');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to use events to pass data from one component to another component like below.

Component A Blade:

```
  <img @click="open = !open" wire:click="showPost({{ $post->id }})" src="{{ $post->image }}" alt="">
```

Component A Class:

```
public function showPost($id){
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->post = $post;
    $this->emit('newPost', $post->id);
  }
```

you can now catch that event from other livewire component like this:

Component B Class:

```
class Post extends Component
{

  public $post;

  protected $listeners = ['newPost'];

  public function mount($id)
  {
    $this->post = \App\Post::find($id);
  }

   public function render()
   {
        return view('livewire.post');
   }

   public function newPost($postId)
   {
       // here u have the id in your other component. 
   }
}
```

you can achieve this other way also. You can pass the id from your component blade as well check [this](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/events) out.

Comment: thank you brother, still wonder use React or Livewire in Laravel, but trying, tkx

Comment: so did you end up with livewire? haha

Comment: Livewire is good where a very minimal user interaction happens ! but when you think of large scale of application where couple thousands to millions of user will interact, you must choose react / vue in order to keep good user experience and your keep your server in good health !

Comment: Is it possible to you pass an object, in stead of a string or integer?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass anything with `@js()` e.g:

```
wire:click="myMethod( @js($myPhpVar) )"
```

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#js-directive